# Android Soundpool fails to play sound

Tags: java, android, android-logcat

I am having trouble with playing multiple sound effects using the SoundPool class. Basically I am making a real time game that involves the user tapping a bunch of objects on the screen. Whenever the player touches an object, I need to play the sound. So I've turned to the SoundPool class. Below is my code:

```
private SoundPool mSoundPool;
private int mSoundId;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PreferencesManager.getInstance(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.arcademode);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mSoundPool = new SoundPool(mBalloonPopCount, R.raw.pop, 0);
    mSoundId = mSoundPool.load(this, R.raw.pop, 1);
}

private void playSound() {
    float actualVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float maxVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
    mSoundPool.play(mSoundId, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
}
```

Now whenever the `playSound()` method is called, I do not hear anything. When I look into LogCat, I see the following lines:

```
08-14 19:48:50.117: ERROR/AudioFlinger(2613): invalid stream type
08-14 19:48:50.117: ERROR/AudioTrack(15611): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -22
08-14 19:48:50.117: ERROR/SoundPool(15611): Error creating AudioTrack
```

The audio file in question is a **.wav** file. I've also tried **.ogg** and **.mp3** files and they don't work either. The sound file is very small (the .wav file doesn't even take up 60KB) so size isn't the issue...

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was? I am having the same problem and can't solve it.

Answer (score 3):

```
mSoundPool = new SoundPool(mBalloonPopCount, R.raw.pop, 0);
```

needs to be

```
mSoundPool = new SoundPool(mBalloonPopCount, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

From every example I sound of using SoundPool, the volume part is different from what you have. It's like this:

```
float actualVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
float maxVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
```

Comment: Have you tried with another format of audio file? like mp3 or ogg? it can be the file format.

Comment: Yes and it doesn't work. I've even tried other sound files in varying formats and I still get the error.